# Checking if a folder is in the current directory

Tags: python, directory

I want to check if there exist a folder in the current folder my code is in, how can this be done?

What I mean is, we have folder called code_folder, which has the python code, i want to check in this python code if in this code_folder we have another folder called folder_1, if is it exists we can store something in it, if not we creat the folder and store something in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
import os
path = "code_folder"
# Check whether the defined path exists or not
if not os.path.exists(path):
   # Create a new directory
   os.makedirs(path)
   print("The new directory is created!")
else:
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib` for this.

```
if pathlib.Path("path/to/code_folder/folder_1").isdir():
    print("the directory exists")
```

But really, you don't need to check anything, you can just use the `exists_ok` argument of `Path.mkdir`, so just:

```
pathlib.Path("path/to/code_folder/foler_1").mkdir(exists_ok=True)
```